How to push specific file to only one remote?
I do have git repository with 2 remotes.
.git/config looks like
[remote "primary"]
    url = ssh://git@git.primary.com/projectname/android.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/primary/*
[branch "develop"]
    remote = primary
    merge = refs/heads/develop
[remote "secondary"]
    url = git@git.secondary.com:projectname/android.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes//*
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@git.primary.com/projectname/android.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = ssh://git@git.primary.com/projectname/android.git
    pushurl = git@git.secondary.com:projectname/android.git

git.secondary.com is local Forgejo(gitea fork) instance. I have admin access to it.
git.primary.com is corporate repo. I only have write access to branches and need to follow some rules
I need repository on git.secondary.com to have several additional files in specifc subolder (.forgejo/) which shouldn't be pushed to git.primary.com.
I need this to automate running of tests and perform some automated analytics
How I can do that?


How to push specific file to only one remote?

You cannot do that with git. In git, the object type that is pushed and pulled is the commit. A commit consist of a tree (basically, a recursive structure consisting of directories and files) and some metadata (like the commit message, timestamps, information about the author, the parent commit(s) and so on and forth.

I need repository on git.secondary.com to have several additional files in specifc subolder (.forgejo/)

There is a solution though: your .forgejo directory can live in its own separate branch (which is never merged into your master or feature branches). This branch, let's call it secondary will only be pushed to your secondary repository. Every time, before pushing that branch, you merge your master branch into secondary. Since .forgejo does not exist in master, that merge will never touch that directory in .secondary. When you then push secondary to your secondary repo, it will contain the current content of master plus the .forgejo directory. You must never merge secondary into master, because that would add .forgejo to master.
This approach works from the point of view of git; I am not familiar with Forgejo and do not know whether it is workable from a semantic point of view -  i.e. this could become (more) difficult if you require the .forgejo to exist locally for your IDE, or something like that. You'd have to figure that out yourself, or add a followup question.
In any case, you can keep .forgejo locally, and try adding it to your .gitignore as well. That way, when you switch between branches locally, it would stay there, and whenever you work with master (or one of your feature branches if you use those) it would still be there for your IDE. This might or might not get a bit annoying though; first you cannot have different versions of .forgejo in different branches (I don't know if that is a problem for you); second you might run into situations where git refuses certain operations because your working directory is not clean. YMMV.
A second solution would be to switch all of this completely around: add your .forgejo to all your regular branches (master, features, etc.). But employ a separate branch, let's call it primary for your primary repo. Every time you want to push to primary, you merge master into primary, then git rm .forego, and then push to the primary repo. If you want to keep a clean(er) history, you would do the merge operation with the no-commit option, remove .forgejo, and then finalize the merge operation with git commit. This would allow you to have .forgejo locally in all branches, for your IDE. You would never otherwise touch the primary branch. You could also extend this to any number of branches.
In any case, you would optionally create a little tooling script to do all that for you, don't do it manually.

There is no efficient way of doing the as git is not designed to do it. There are only hacks into it
set a branch named test
run :
git push secondary test

for your local dev
and when you plan to merge changes to primary
first merge changes to master(in your local mashine) using a git diff tool (do not merge the .forgejo/ folder ) how to do this depend on the diff tool you are using
then
git push primary master

